# How to select selected value from multiple option using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I have multiple select topion.

And I need to show the selected values.with the data of '2,4,5;

```
<select id="testID" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">test Value1</option>
   <option value="2">test Value2</option>
   <option value="3">test Value3</option>
   <option value="4">test Value4</option>
   <option value="5">test Value5</option>
  <option value="6">test Value6</option>
</select>
```

Can I use this code to get what I need.

```
<script type="javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var val_to_select = '2,4,5';    

    $( '#testID' ).val( val_to_select );

  )};

</script>
```

I need output to be like this

```
<select id="testID" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">test Value1</option>
   <option value="2" selected>test Value2</option>
   <option value="3">test Value3</option>
   <option value="4" selected>test Value4</option>
   <option value="5" selected>test Value5</option>
  <option value="6">test Value6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the value in an array like this

```
$("#testID").val([1,2,3]);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jmw43wo/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
var data="1,2,4";

//Make an array

var dataarray=data.split(",");

// Set the value

$("#testID").val(dataarray);

// Then refresh

$("#testID").multiselect("refresh");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="testID" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">test Value1</option>
   <option value="2">test Value2</option>
   <option value="3">test Value3</option>
   <option value="4">test Value4</option>
   <option value="5">test Value5</option>
  <option value="6">test Value6</option>
</select>
```

Also your code is not javascript but jquery.